# Does pandassql support all mysql commands?

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

I am new to pandas. I am able to sub-queries with pandas-sql module. pandas-sql doesn't come with Anaconda distribution. So i have done !pip install pandasql

Does pandas sql support all MySQL queries? and which one is preferred native pandas method or calling MySQL queries in pandas sql, or both are same.

SQL

`SELECT ID FROM df2`

Pandas

`df2['ID']`

sample example is below

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1231, 'Customer A', '123 Street', np.nan],
               [1232, 'Customer A', np.nan, '333 Street'],
               [1233, 'Customer B', '444 Street', '333 Street'],
              [1234, 'Customer B', '444 Street', '666 Street']], columns=
['ID', 'Customer', 'Billing Address', 'Shipping Address'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1231,   'apple'],
               [1232, 'orange'],
               [1233, 'mango'],
              [1234, np.nan],
              [1300, np.nan]], columns=
['ID', 'item'])
q3 = """SELECT ID,item FROM df2 where ID in (SELECT ID from df1)"""
print(ps.sqldf(q3, locals()))
```

Out

```
    ID    item
0  1231   apple
1  1232  orange
2  1233   mango
3  1234    None
```

Pandas

```
df_n = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID')
df_n[['ID','item']]

    ID  item
0   1231    apple
1   1232    orange
2   1233    mango
3   1234    NaN
```

Comment: Have you read the docs of the library you are using?

Comment: `pandasql` is an [SQLAlchemy wrapper](https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/blob/master/pandasql/sqldf.py) to regular engine calls and pandas' `read_sql` and `to_sql`.

Comment: which one is preferred native pandas method or calling MySQL queries in pandas sql, or both are same.